# The number of maximal cliques of the intersection graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Are there some results about the upper bound of the number of maximal cliques (NMC) of some class of intersection graphs?

I want to know whether some classic classes of intersection graphs have polynomial many of NMC (with respect to $n$, the size of the given graph).

I only know that the NMC of chordal graphs is at most $n$.

I also find some efficient algorithms for listing all the maximal cliques.
For example, [we can list all maximal cliques on trapezoid graphs in $O(n^{2} + \gamma n)$](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00207160212707), where $\gamma$ is the size of the output.
However, do we know the trapezoid graphs or permutation graphs have polynomial many NMC?

Answer (score 1):

You might already know about this, but there is a result of Farber (in https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(89)90268-9) that states graphs with no induced $C_4$ have quadratically many maximal cliques.

For permutation graphs, the answer is "no": the complement of $nK_2$ is a permutation graph, and $nK_2$ has $2^n$ maximal stable sets.

Answer (score 1):

One known result due to Brimkov et al. is that intersection graphs of convex polytopes in $\mathbb R^n$ with a bounded number of $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplanes to which the facets of the polytopes are parallel, have a polynomial number of maximal cliques.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X18301458?via%3Dihub